# getting wrong IP address in php

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

i have following php code to get vistor ip

```
 function VisitorIP()
  { 
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
  $TheIp=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  else $TheIp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  return trim($TheIp);
  }
  $Users_IP_address = VisitorIP();
```

but every time i execute this script on my localhost i got  ::1 as IP

how can i get exact internet IP & system IP address
because my script will run on LAN nwteork and i want to record IP of lan pcs & internet IP and save it in mysql database.

i need PHP code which privide local system IP and system internet IP.

Thanks

Comment: ::1 is your IPv6 address

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you are getting the right IP. `::1` is your loopback (localhost) IPv6 address.

Answer (score 2):

First, throw this stupid function away, because HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is not an IP address but merely an HTTP header, and make it just

```
$Users_IP_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Next, you have to set up your server to work with ipv4, not ipv6.
Though it is not really a PHP question and should be asked on the serverfault, provided with full system setup: OS, version, your rights etc.

Comment: see i want a PHP code which privide local system IP and internet IP of system.

Comment: @air you have to reconfigure your server. What is `Listen` parameter value in the apache's htttpd.comf file?

Answer (score 1):

When you run above script on localhost you can get `::1` this result.

It's very common.

If you want to get your system IP address with localhost use this code.

1) Script for `localhost`

```
<?PHP

$ip = @file_get_contents("http://www.apps-tube.com/apps/ip-address/ip.php");

echo $ip;

?>
```

2) Script for `Servers`

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]


?>
```

Comment: I removed the link to the "get my IP" service on your website. That is *not* related to this question, and you failed to indicate it was your site, anyway.